# AWS beanstalk display html code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I developed my java web app on intelli j (java 8) and i store it on aws beanstalk and i use the tomcat preset for it. Everything is fine but it is displaying the html code on the site. It thinks it is related to the out.println("") in the servlet but I have no idea how to solve the problem.

what it is diplaying :

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Raid HEI - Le Raid</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-                                
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png">
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script><body>

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-
 large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" 
 title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">`
```

servlet code :

```
@WebServlet("/index")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "<title>Raid HEI - Le Raid</title>\n" +
            "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
            "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n" +
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css\">\n" +
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato\">\n" +
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\">\n" +
            "<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"images/logo.png\">\n" +
            "<script src=\"js/script.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>"+
            "<body>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<!-- Navbar -->\n" +
            "<nav class=\"w3-top\">\n" +
            "  <div class=\"w3-bar w3-black w3-card\">\n" +
            "    <a class=\"w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"myFunction()\" title=\"Toggle Navigation Menu\"><i class=\"fa fa-bars\"></i></a>\n" +
            "    <div class=\"w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small\">\n" +
```

1-[what it is diplaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlTu8.png)          2-[servlet code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz7im.png)

Comment: Don't hesitate posting code right here, it's way better than reading screenshots

Comment: Have you set the `Content-Type` in the response?  Your code cuts off before we can tell for sure.